# How to copy data from one database table to another in rotation using PHP/MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm new to programming, I'm trying to insert data from a database table into another table in the same database in a rotation manner and a bit confused how to go about it.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what a rotation manner is?

Comment: I meant to say the data to be copied from the first table would be copied per execution, I have up to 4 different users whose data I want to copy to a new table once a form is filled and submitted.

Comment: If you want an insert to a table to TRIGGER and an insert,update or delete on another table then a TRIGGER may be what you need.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html